# JAX-RS @Path in Composed Annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jax-rs

This one seems relatively straightforward. I'm messing around with composed annotations, and I'm trying to do the following:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Path("")
public @interface TestAnnotation {
  @AliasFor(annotation = Path.class, attribute = "value")
  String path();
}
```

This does not work. When I use it like so:

```
@Path("")
public class MyResource {
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @TestAnnotation(path = "/things")
  public void postIt(Thing myThing) {
    // Do various things and then return a Response
  }
}
```

...I receive a `405` in return. If I do this:

```
// Remove class-level @Path
// @Path("")
public class MyResource {
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @TestAnnotation(path = "/things")
  public void postIt(Thing myThing) {
    // Do various things and then return a Response
  }
}
```

...I receive a `404` in return.

There is just something about `@Path` or the fact that `@Path` has a required `value` attribute that results in this just not functioning, and I have no idea how to remedy it.

Comment: Your class need's a `@Path` or it won't be discovered as a resource class, i.e. never get registered, i.e. 404

Comment: @peeskillet That doesn't explain the `405` I get if I include the class-level `@Path`.

Comment: Do you know what a 405 means?

Comment: Also do you know if `@AliasFor` is _compiled_ by Spring to some differen bytecode, or if it is just _processed_ by Spring? If the latter, I don't see why it should be recognized by JAX-RS. These are two completely different processing engines.

Comment: @peeskillet As far as I know, `405` is a simple "Method Not Allowed," which is why it's so baffling; I'm sending a `POST` to a `POST` endpoint. I can only guess that it's freaking out for some reason and trying to hit some other endpoint path. As for `@AliasFor`, I can only say that my real "`TestAnnotation`" involves more JAX-RS-related meta-annotations than this simplified example, and that they do actually function - `@Path` is the only one not cooperating.

Comment: I don't know where else you are using the annotation, but I imagine it involves Spring somehow (not completely JAX-RS processed). The @Path works differently. Unlessed it is _compiled_ to different byte code by Spring, it shouldn't work. JAX-RS uses this annotation to create an underlying  resource model on startup, which it uses to direct traffic.

Comment: Basically, Spring has no part in request routing. This is _all_ handled by JAX-RS. So if the annotation is not compiled by Spring to the correct byte code, there is no way for JAX-RS to correctly handle the expecting routing.

Comment: How confident are you that you are in fact sending a POST?  What do you get if you send an OPTIONS method to the /things endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimentation and research, it would appear that what I am trying to do is literally not possible.

A follow-up attempt was made to utilize Jackson's `@JsonView` and expose it through my composed annotation via Spring's `@AliasFor`, and this also failed to function.

I spent some time thinking about how annotations work and considering peeskillet's comments about compilation vs. processing, and I have come to the conclusion that both Jersey and Jackson must use annotation processors that basically just call "Method.isAnnotationPresent()" for detection of relevant annotations. Spring's `@AliasFor` most likely does not compile nor weave the aliased meta-annotations into the byte-code of the target methods, and thus they are not found by the processors.

My personal solution to this problem was to drop JAX-RS entirely and use Spring's `@RequestMapping`, which *can* be aliased in a composed annotation, and to just accept that Jackson's `@JsonView` simply can't be integrated into a composed annotation.

Obviously, this is not an ideal solution for most people, especially those with large, already established systems. In such situations, it is more likely that the idea of composed annotations will be abandoned long before JAX-RS.

So if anyone has some more insight into the problem, or someone directly from the Spring team wants to chime in, feel free.